# Is reading from /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail draining entropy?

Tags: linux, random-number-generator

When I'm doing `watch cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, the amount of entropy steadily decreases, until I get about 150-200. Initially I get over 2000. When I stop reading that value and wait a minute or two, and then read it again, I am at about 2000 again. Why is reading that value reducing the entropy?

Comment: It was answered on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13170334/1418463). Main point is that creating a process does consume entropy. `cat` is a process, thus running `watch cat` consumes entropy.

Comment: OK. I did. Only because you asked. I feel like I just only retyped data from one place to another... Meanwhile I did learn this as well, because I did not know it before.

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96847/22222

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main point here is that **creating a process will consume some amount of entropy**.

As stated in comments in the blog post [Entropy Broken](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2011/03/entropy-broken) entropy is needed at least for randomization of the address space layout.

`cat` is a process, thus running `watch cat ...` will be consuming entropy constantly. Obviously, when you kill `watch` your system is restoring entropy to the usual level.